# Error con PHP al guardar datos en mysql

Tags: php, html

Estoy intentando guardar en mysql los datos que introduzcan en los formulario
pero el php me esta dondo errores como este: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in C:\wamp\www\Tarea2\index.php on line 5`

Aqui el codigo:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btnGuardar'])){
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","Elvisdt17","taveras17","personas");

    $nombre = _POST['nombre'];
    $apellido = _POST['apellido'];
    $tel = _POST['telefono'];
    $email = _POST['email'];
    $dir = _POST['direccion'];
    $sexo = _POST['sexo'];
    $sangre = _POST['tipoSangre'];
    $cedula = _POST['cedula'];

    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO gente (Nombre, Apellido, Sexo, Telefono, Email, Cedula, Direccion, Tipo_sangre)
       VALUES('$nombre', '$apellido', '$sexo', '$tel', '$email', '$cedula', '$dir', '$sangre')");
    mysqli_close($con);
}?>
```

Me podrían ayudar?

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque es un error tipográfico y no una pregunta de código, sin valor para futuros lectores.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

el problema en tu codigo es el que te faltan los signos $ de las variables `$_POST`
Tienes:

```
$nombre = _POST['nombre'];
$apellido = _POST['apellido'];
$tel = _POST['telefono'];
$email = _POST['email'];
$dir = _POST['direccion'];
$sexo = _POST['sexo'];
$sangre = _POST['tipoSangre'];
$cedula = _POST['cedula'];
```

El cual debería ser :

```
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
    $tel = $_POST['telefono'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $dir = $_POST['direccion'];
    $sexo = $_POST['sexo'];
    $sangre = $_POST['tipoSangre'];
    $cedula = $_POST['cedula'];
```

Comment: Publicaste mientras estaba escribiendo la respuesta antes de votar para cerrarla.. +1 ... Creo que se debería **[aceptar](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/427/127)** esta respuesta, pero se debería leer [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/127)

Answer (score 2):

Hola amigo te falta el signo del dolar y seleccionar la base de datos.
Prueba de esta manera:

```php
<?php
if (isset($_POST['btnGuardar'])) {

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "Elvisdt17", "taveras17", "personas");

    mysqli_select_db($con, "personas");
    $nombre   = $_POST['nombre'];
    $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
    $tel      = $_POST['telefono'];
    $email    = $_POST['email'];
    $dir      = $_POST['direccion'];
    $sexo     = $_POST['sexo'];
    $sangre   = $_POST['tipoSangre'];
    $cedula   = $_POST['cedula'];

    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO gente (Nombre, Apellido, Sexo, Telefono, Email, Cedula, Direccion, Tipo_sangre) VALUES('" . $nombre . "', '" . $apellido . "', '" . $sexo . "', '" . $tel . "', '" . $email . "', '" . $cedula . "', '" . $dir . "', '" . $sangre . "')");
    mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Te olvidaste del signo `$` ... `_POST['algo']` debería ser `$_POST['algo']`:

```
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
$tel = $_POST['telefono'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$dir = $_POST['direccion'];
$sexo = $_POST['sexo'];
$sangre = $_POST['tipoSangre'];
$cedula = $_POST['cedula'];
```

Y por otro lado, **MUY IMPORTANTE**, tu código tiene vulnerabilidades de seguridad que deberías atender. Por favor lee:

[¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/127)

Comment: Debiste comenzar desde el princio si sabias la solución a la pregunta no a la primera votar para cerrarla, quizas no tenga valor o fundamentos para futuros lectores pero te olvidas que no todos tienen el mismo conocimiento sin embargo para los que recien comienza en programación de seguro les servira, no entiendo cual es el problema si no colocan el error del problema no es aceptada ahora si les dicen quiero un sistema tal tal mencionan quieres que escriba el código por ti si crean una pregunta de calidad un sistema avanzado para mejoras tampoco. Logica al sentido quien los entiende?

Comment: @J.Doe Podrás ver que publiqué **antes** de votar. En cuanto a quienes recién comienzan, en mi opinión, es prácticamente imposible que encuentren esta solución cuando tengan el mismo problema. Para el resto, te recomiendo plantear el tema en [meta].

Comment: En ***StackOverflow*** los registros de usuarios a esta plataforma no posee restricción para usuarios de desconocimientos... Por lo tanto solo imagina que la respuesta no fue respondida este nuevl usuario crearia nuevas preguntas similares por el simple echo de no darle saber el simple error que estaba comentiendo

Comment: Respondido en [este comentario](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24017/error-con-php-al-guardar-datos-en-mysql?noredirect=1#comment38887_24017) y esperando tu pregunta que busque respuestas canónicas o tu publicación en [meta]